# Puppet: 'creates' does not create a new file

Tags: puppet

I would like to run a command, only if a file does not exist.

This is what I tried:

```
exec { 'test':
  command => '/usr/bin/echo Test',
  creates => '/etc/test/test-init'
}
```

But unfortunately this file is not being created. The puppet agent works without throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

The `creates` parameter of an `Exec` does not cause *Puppet* to create the designated file.  Rather it instructs Puppet to use the existence of that file to determine whether the command should be run, on the supposition that *the command* will create it when it runs.

That's often used with commands that naturally create a file or directory, but you can do it synthetically, too.  For example:

```
exec { 'test':
  command => '/usr/bin/echo Test && touch /etc/test/test-init',
  creates => '/etc/test/test-init',
  provider => 'shell'
}
```